# What are good early-game sources of money?

Tags: house-of-many-doors

Once you're past the opening, A House Of Many Doors doesn't have terribly much direction. So you wander around, fighting unspeakable monsters, exploring strange cities, and eating strange food for quite some time. But sooner or later, you start running out of fuel, and need to repeatedly spend money on shore leave to boost your sanity. And then, perhaps, one of your officers invites the entire crew to a fine dinner and sticks you with the bill, to the tune of a few hundred guineas.

Each city buys and sells a seemingly-random cross-section of the possible goods, and finding stuff you can actually sell for money in the wilderness is fairly random – there's random goodies scattered around, but combat usually costs you more than you gain, and again there's that problem of finding the right places to sell your loot.

The point is: in the early game, it's hard to find any reliable way to earn money. How can I earn enough money to keep me in fuel, sanity, and repairs so I can explore more of the content? Say, a few thousand guineas, so I can even upgrade a thing or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing the game for several hours, here are the easy sources of early-game money I found:

- The City of Engines (southwest of the City of Keys, the starting city) has an automaton that's seeking one of each type of memory that you can stuff into a Memory Box, and it will pay ~350G each. There are about six types of memory that you can stuff into a box, so that's around 2000G total. You'll find the memories semi-randomly as you explore the House and visit various cities.
- The information-brokers of the game will buy a Glimpse of Another World for about 150G. You can find said Glimpses in several random encounters of the House. (Ghoulwatch pays the best for a Glimpse: 90G plus a Fetch-Mirror, which is both useful in-and-of-itself or can be sold for 200G in the City of Keys)
- Several random events in the House give you valuable items:

  - Wells are always good: some give you an automatic Glimpse, some can get you a choice between Glimpse or Bottled Darkness. (Bottled Darkness sells for 500G in the City of Keys, once you've found the black market in a random event.)
  - A shack with a human cowering in it gives you two items: a Glimpse when you ask how he got there, and a Human Prisoner (which you can press-gang into your lower-deck crew while you're in a city)
- If you're desperate, you can sell your starting Fetch-Mirror for 200G in the City of Keys. You don't really need instant travel until you can comfortably afford to throw away 200G at a time.
- The newspapers in the City of Keys will purchase news from you, for 50G to 100G, plus bonuses for how far away the news came from.
- Incriminating Evidence should be sold for 500G+, but the price differs per broker. You can get Incriminating Evidence: The Governor fairly early by following Rotherford's storyline.
- 10 Lurid Tales can be converted into 2000G in your lodgings. I seem to find lots of Lurid Tales in the Chimeric Empire, a ways north-east of the City of Keys.

In general, A House of Many Doors is much less cash-poor than, say, the very-similar game Sunless Sea. You're almost never going to run so low on money that you die from the inability to purchase fuel. But earning a *lot* of money is still hard.